# Default multiple comparison correction in TukeyHSD in R?

Tags: r, tukey-hsd-test

Does anyone know what the default method is for adjusting for multiple comparisons is in the TukeyHSD function? (e.g. BH, Bonferroni, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The [Turkey HSD (honest significant difference) test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test) is itself a procedure for statistical testing that takes into account multiple comparisons. It's based on the [Studentized range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_range) distribution of the difference between the maximum and minimum of a set of a number of values (expressed in terms of sample standard deviations). The multiple-comparisons issue is handled by the incorporation of the number of values being compared (mean values, in this case) as a parameter of the Studentized range distribution.

Tukey's HSD attempts to control [family-wise error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate) so in that sense it is more similar to the Bonferroni correction than to the Benjamin-Hochberg [false discovery rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate) approach. But it is a test of its own and depends on no other correction for multiple comparisons.